# Can we use glmtree for negative binomial distribution?

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, party

I'm trying to create a conditional inference tree predicting number of root grafts in relation to distance between roots and number of roots. My variable response has a negative binomial distribution but in glmtree function there is no Negative binomial family. Is there an alternative in R ?

Answer (score 1):

No, `glmtree()` does not support negative binomial regression (at least not when the overdispersion parameter `theta` has to be estimated). But you can easily use the `quasipoisson` family which also adjusts for overdispersion.

Other alternatives would be to use a nonparametric `ctree()` instead of the parametric negative binomial approach. Possibly, a `sqrt()` transformation of the response helps.

Or you can roll your own model-based recursive partitioning algorithm using the general `mob()` function, see `vignette("mob", package = "partykit")`.

As an example for the two parametric approaches, I'm using the `RecreationDemand` data from the `AER` package. And for the negative binomial regression I'm interfacing `glm.nb()` from `MASS`:

```
data("RecreationDemand", package = "AER")
library("partykit")
tr_qpois <- glmtree(trips ~ quality | ski + income + costS,
  data = RecreationDemand, family = quasipoisson, minsize = 30)

library("MASS")
negbin <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...) {
  glm.nb(y ~ 0 + x, start = start, ...)
}
tr_negbin <- mob(trips ~ quality | ski + income + costS,
  data = RecreationDemand, fit = negbin, control = mob_control(minsize = 30))
```

I'm restricting the minimal sample size per leaf to 30 observations to stabilize the estimation of the negbin model. However, when fitting the tree and searching the split point some warnings are issued nevertheless. Also, the way `glm.nb()` estimates the `theta` parameter is relatively slow which is why the corresponding tree is rather slow.

The resulting tree structure is not identical but quite similar:

```
plot(tr_qpois)
```

[image: quasi-poisson tree]

```
plot(tr_negbin)
```

[image: negative binomial tree]

While `mob()` allows you to easily fit the tree, it does not have all the convenience features of plotting and predicting that `glmtree()` has, though.